# Git submodule cloned to wrong path

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have two git repositories that are nearly identical. They both have a submodule dependency, called AlphaFilePath.

They have identical `.gitmodules` files:

```
[submodule "AlphaFilePath "]
        path = AlphaFilePath
        url = (URL)
```

However, when cloning the two repositories, repository A clones AlphaFilePath submodule into `alphafilepath`, where repository B clones it into `AlphaFilePath` like I wanted. This is troublesome for make files and git is unable to run `submodule update` on repository A because there is no module defined for that file.

Where is this cloned path defined, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this with a simple `git mv alphafilepath AlphaFilePath` to rename the submodule.

Committing this change allowed new contributors to clone the repository and see the submodule cloned to the appropriate case-sensitive path, thus fixing the issue. What trips me up is that simply locally renaming the folder with `mv alphafilepath AlphaFilePath` did not mark the folder as dirty in git (on Windows, anyway), so `git mv` was the key.